# Can the genesis block of bitcoin be put to qr codes?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I Think I own the genesis block it really eats my name.it has my real name on it
with QR codes.WHen I check it from Blockchain site its the same as the one I got.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.StackExchange! I am having trouble understanding what exactly you are asking. The genesis block in Bitcoin is hard-coded, and therefore cannot be spent. Can you edit your question to be a bit more specific?

Comment: I use an old version of wallet address  bitcoinwallet.com then I put my name on it using my ninja name kingkiromomochi.bitcoinwallet.com. then i put my name i was surprised half a second when i address it using the genesis block.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  its the one that starts with 1A1 then ends in DivfNa. that nonces must be waiting for me for along time.